# Angular2 import shortcut

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I'm developping an app using angular 2 and webpack. I was wondering, is there a way to make shortcuts for imports? What I mean is that I need sometimes to import components from folders that are up in the hierarchy so I end up doing something like this.

```
import { UserComponent } from '../../../models/users/user.ts';
```

Ideally just want to do:

```
import {UserComponent} from '@models/users/user.ts';
```

or something even shorter. Is there a way to create shortcuts?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure \`baseUrl\` for typescript compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059205/how-to-configure-baseurl-for-typescript-compiler)

Comment: baseUrl is all that TS has got. Using any preprocessor to create shortcuts will result in losing the support from IDEs, and that's the last thing the one usually wants.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is many, many years old, and we have Angular 7, but in case someone has the same question, here's an answer.

You can configure path-mapping in the file `tsconfig.json`.

For example: Given that we have the following folder structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── ...
│   └── shared
│       └── material
│           └── material.module.ts
...
...
```

I would like to add a "shortcut" the folder `shared`. Therefore I add `"@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]` in the `compilerOptions` of the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
    },
   // ... and so on
```

Now I can Import my shared module like this:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@shared/material/material.module';
```

Hope this helps someone.

Details can be found in the [Typescript Documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).